# how to convert kml file to pdf

Tags: kml

I have downloaded a kml file from https://www.genesys-pgr.org/explore/map but I don't have a tool to support it. How can I convert the xml file to pdf or word file?

Comment: Note that KML is an XML file format so you can load the file in a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Converting a KML file to a PDF is not straightforward and the solution really depends on what you want to do with the PDF file. KML or [Keyhole Markup Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language) is simply a collection of geospatial annotations on a map that can be opened in an application that supports that data format. KML itself is a shareable file format that can be emailed from one user to another to share places on the map.

If you just want to view the KML file recommend you download and install [Google Earth Pro](https://www.google.com/earth/desktop/), which is freely provided by Google. There are other viewers for KML available.

One way to convert KML to PDF is the following steps:

1. Open the KML file with Google Earth Pro
2. Change the view on the map to view you want to save in the PDF file. For example, tilt the map and/or zoom on the map.
3. Next take a screenshot of the Google Earth map or select save image option in the menu to save the map view as a JPEG image.
4. Insert that JPEG image into a Word document and/or then save it as a PDF file.

Comment: Thanks Jason but is there any other way around? The problem is Google Earth is not working on my laptop and I need to convert the file on urgent basis as I need to incorporate it for a publication.

Comment: You could upload the KML file into [Google Maps](http://mymaps.google.com) or could open it with [QGIS](https://qgis.org/en/site/)